# how does closure work when declaring anonymous functions in javascript(jquery) calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this function:

```
var x = {
  getStuff : function(){
     var i = 0;
     $.getJSON('/url.json', {}, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key,val){ 
          alert(i);
        });            
     });
  });
}
```

So am I understanding correctly that the anonymous functions declared for the 2 jquery calls (.getJSON, .each) both have access to the parent function(getStuff) due to closure?

Does that mean that the anonymous functions are being declared in that location are within the scope chain of its parent so they have access to the parents variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anonymous functions don't have access to "getStuff()" itself, by that name, except via the variable "x". They *do* have access to the variable "i", or more correctly to the variable "i" in the instantiation of the containing function's local scope for the invocation in which the anonymous functions were instantiated.

Each call to "getStuff()" will create a new local scope, each with it's own "i" and its own anonymous functions.

Comment: So when you talk about its own "i", if I change that "i" will it be changed across all the objects which reference the "x" variable due to the literal syntax?

Comment: @James: No - upon entering the execution context of the functions a _new_ _VariableObject_ (VA) is created, with new properties (linked to eg. _i_) - this object will be put on the scope chain on any functions created/entered _in_ that context, and so these will have access to that specific instance of _i_. But for each time the function is entered, a new scope is formed.

Comment: @James what Sean wrote above is correct. Each call to "getStuff()" allocates a fresh block of storage, which means a fresh "i".